# Add comments to hive tables using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am creating hive tables via PySpark.

Is there a way to add comments to each column before being written into hive?

Example:

> df = spark.table('sometable')
>    # add comments       df.write.saveAsTable('mytablewithcomments')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to **`pyspark shell`**

```
bash$ pyspark
>>> spark.sql("create table cmnt(id string COMMENT 'new')")
```

**`Then login to hive cli:`**

```
hive> desc formatted cmnt;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

id                      string                  new
```

Then you can see comments in hive table!

Comment: Thanks @Shu , Is it possible to add comments while saving the table from pyspark?Eg: df.write.saveAsTable('mytable') so that mytable has comments to each column.

Comment: @gr.kr, I don't think that is possible, we can only add comments to the columns while creating hive table!

Comment: Thanks for the response Shu

Answer (score 7):

The `alias` method of the column class takes a `metadata` option which may include a comment.

```
df_with_column_comment = df.select( df.col.alias( 'col',
    metadata = { 'comment': 'Column description' }
) )
```

As far as I know, columns are immutable, so you cannot add a comment after it is created.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE table_name(  column1 STRING,  column2 STRING COMMENT "some comment",  column3 LONG) USING csv OPTIONS (header true, path '/data/table.csv')`

Comment: I am looking for something using pyspark.

Comment: And not using hiveql

Comment: @gr.kr you can use spark SQL to create the table with comments.

Comment: Thanks @dassum , I was looking to create table on the fly using df.write.saveAsTable('') with comments on each column.

Comment: FWIW, it appears to provide [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/3399890), even if that answer isn't useful to the question asker.  If it is incorrect, that's what down voting is for.