# How to specify table comment while using saveToTable in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using spark SQL, we can use the `COMMENT` option to set a table comment with `CREATE STATEMENT`. Is there an option to set it while doing `saveToTable`? Or is there a way to set the table comment after it has been created?

Comment: Similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917626/add-comments-to-hive-tables-using-pyspark